# Combining two queries from the same table?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that keeps records of users that answered a question, with the number of trials. It's like:

```
username trials
-------- ------
user1    10
user2    7
user1    20
```

etc. From which I can calculate how many times they answered a question (`COUNT`).
and now I want to calculate average number of trials, i.e. get the following table:

```
username avg
-------- ---
user1    15
user2    7
```

I've tried this query:

```
SELECT(a.totalguess/b.totalknow) as avg FROM( SELECT username, SUM(trials) AS totalguess FROM thetable GROUP BY username) a, (SELECT username, COUNT(*) as totalknow FROM thetable GROUP BY username)b WHERE a.username=b.username;
```

and it gave only

```
avg
---
15
7
```

pretty close! but without the knowers. I could probably combine them with php, but I want a pure MySQL solution. So what should I do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A simple query (with no inline views) using expression `AVG(trials)` would be the most efficient way return this result set. See the answer (+1!) from dnagirl. Note that MySQL is going to materialize any inline views as intermediate ("derived") MyISAM tables, and then run the outer query against the "derived" tables, which can be a performance issue with large sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.knower, (a.totalguess/b.totalknow) as avg 
FROM (SELECT knower, SUM(trials) AS totalguess FROM thetable GROUP BY knower) a, 
     (SELECT knower, COUNT(*) as totalknow FROM thetable GROUP BY knower)b 
WHERE a.knower=b.knower;
```

or simply:

```
SELECT knower, SUM(trials)/COUNT(*) as avg -- or you can just use AVG(trials)
FROM thetable 
GROUP BY knower
```

Comment: I tried pretty much the same, but with 2 SELECT's at the beginning :) thank you very much! p.s.: I will be able to accept this answer in 9 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT username as knower, AVG(trials) as theavg
FROM mytable
GROUP BY username
```

will give you this:

```
knower, theavg

user1, 15
user2, 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one query:

```
      SELECT knower, SUM(trials)/count(*)
      from thetable
      group by knower
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial SELECT statement determines what columns will be returned. Right now you have

```
SELECT(a.totalguess/b.totalknow) as avg FROM ...
```

So you will only get one column called "avg" back. So add the knower to your select list.

```
SELECT a.knower as knower,
       (a.totalguess/b.totalknow) as avg
FROM
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT knower, AVG(trials) FROM thetable GROUP BY knower
```

Comment: why are you doing `AVG(COUNT(trials))` instead of `AVG(trials)`?  For user1, the count of trials is 2. The average would therefore be 2/2=1

Comment: @dnagirl Because I misunderstood the question. Answer updated accordingly, thanks for the catch!